# Travis: How do I enable pip and directory caching simultaenously?

Tags: travis-ci

For pip caching I put in my `.travis.yml`:

```
cache: pip
```

For directory caching I put in my `.travis.yml`:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - data/
```

What can I do to enable both types of caching simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

We can set `cache` to a hashmap where `pip: true`.

```
cache:
  pip: true
  directories:
    - data/
```

(reference: [Travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#enabling-multiple-caching-features))